# Given the lengths of two sides of a triangle, is it possible to obtain (sharp) bounds for the average length of the sides of the triangle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, triangles, average

The title says it all.

> Given the lengths of two sides of a triangle, is it possible to obtain (sharp) bounds for the average length of the sides of the triangle?

Let the lengths of two sides of the triangle be $a$ and $b$.  Then the length $c$ of the third side is bounded, by the [Triangle Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), as follows:
$$|a - b| < c < a + b.$$

Another way to state it is
$$\max(a, b, c) < a + b + c - \max(a, b, c)$$
implying
$$2\cdot\max(a, b, c) < a + b + c.$$
Consequently, a lower bound for the average length of the sides of the triangle is given by
$$\frac{2}{3}\cdot\max(a, b, c) < \frac{a + b + c}{3}.$$

My questions are as follows:

> > 1. Is it possible to obtain a sharper lower bound for $(a + b + c)/3$?
> > 2. Is it possible to obtain a sharp upper bound for $(a + b + c)/3$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) given $a,b,\gamma$ to be respectively two sides ($a \ge b$) and the angle in between you get that
$$c^2 = a^2+b^2-2ab\cos \gamma$$
so the average of the three sides is
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3} = \frac{a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos \gamma}}{3}$$
Now note that

- the minimum of the average is when $\cos \gamma = 1 \Rightarrow$
  $$\frac{a+b+c}{3} = \frac{a+b+\sqrt{a^2-2ab+b^2}}{3} = \frac{a+b+\sqrt{(a-b)^2}}{3} = \frac{2a}{3}$$
- the maximum is when $\cos \gamma = -1 \Rightarrow$
  $$\frac{a+b+c}{3} = \frac{a+b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab}}{3} = \frac{a+b+\sqrt{(a+b)^2}}{3} = \frac{2(a+b)}{3}$$
  so
  $$\frac{2a}{3} \le \frac{a+b+c}{3} \le \frac{2(a+b)}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sirfoga!  Just what I needed.  =)

Comment: edited to make it clearer!

Comment: The final answer for the minimum of the average is of course for the case when $a \geq b$.  In general, we have
$$\min\left(\frac{a + b + c}{3}\right) = \frac{a + b + \sqrt{(a - b)^2}}{3} = \frac{a + b + |a - b|}{3} = \frac{2}{3}\cdot\max(a, b).$$

Comment: Yup! my lower bound is when $\gamma = 0$ and thus it is not a proper triangle ..

Comment: Your maximum is not a proper triangle either.

Comment: Yup, I know .. it comes as it is 2 segments .,